# Data Not Being Added to MySQL Service

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

I have created 2 services, a MySQL service and a Go Web Server service. The MySQL service loads data from a .mysql file I exported via phpmyadmin. All works fine on my local machine, services are created, db script executes creating the DB schema and populating it with my data.

When I deploy to DigitalOcean however, the db script does not seem execute. My services are created but I just get an empty database. I can't figure out why, the db file is definitely located in the path I am using so that is not the issues.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.2
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: temppass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: tempdb
    volumes:
      - /path/to/data:/var/lib/mysql
  web:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, for whatever reason the `/var/lib/sql` path works fine in my local docker container to import my .mysql dump but when on DigitalOcean I had to replace my volume mapping to this:

```
 - ./data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```